# Using Django signals during the update instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, celery

I have a project on Django Rest Framework, RabbitMQ and Celery.

After sending a post request to create a mailing instance via API, Celery should send messages, and the Celery task number is saved in the mailing instance. The same should happen if you create a mailing instance in the Django admin panel. The mailing instance can be edited both through API and through the Django admin panel (in this case, the outdated Celery task is deleted and a new one is created, the number of the new Celery task is saved in the mailing instance).

I solved this problem by overriding the methods in ModelViewSet (DRF) and ModelAdmin (Django).

But I would like to solve the problem by using Django signals (on the one hand, this worsens the readability of the code, on the other hand, it eliminates the need to redefine methods). There are no problems with creating and deleting mailing instances and Celery tasks. But I can't create a signal that correctly handles the mailing instance update (the pre_save and post_save signals trigger a cyclic update of the mailing object). `Mailing instance update -> a signal is triggered -> a Celery task is created -> the task number is saved in the instance -> a signal is triggered...` and so on...

Is it possible to solve the problem using signals? What are the best practices in this regard?

Comment: We should always avoid signals they have lot of issues one possible being they are synchronous which defeats the purpose of even driven programming approach. You can do anything without signals by offloading the task like you are already doing using celery.